# I need some understanding of the routing of a multi module Phalcon application

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I need some help with a multi module Phalcon application. I followed the instructions as per https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple but cannot get the variable routing working for the non default module.

```
$router = new Router();
$router->setDefaultModule("admin");
$router->setDefaultAction('index');
```

This works for the `admin` module:

```
$router->add("/:controller/:action/:params", array(
    'module' => 'admin',
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 2,
    'params' => 3
));
```

This works only works for the `api` module (the not default module) when set manually:

```
$router->add("/api", array(
    'module' => 'api',
    'controller' => 'index'
));

$router->add("/api/user", array(
    'module' => 'api',
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action' => 'index'
));
```

But this won't work for the `api` module:

```
$router->add("/api/:controller/:action/:params", array(
    'module' => 'api',
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 2,
    'params' => 3
));
```

I then get an error like below when I use /api or /api/user:

```
\www\site\public\index.php:104:string 'admin\controllers\ApiController handler class cannot be loaded'
```

But when I access /api/user/index it works. It looks like for the not default module it forgets the `setDefaultAction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing routes with default controller, actions:

```
$router->add("/api/:controller", array(
    'module' => 'api',
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 'index',
));
$router->add("/api", array(
    'module' => 'api',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index',
));
```

Phalcon needs routes to be strictly specified, otherwise it's not going to resolve them. We're paying this price for routing's high performance.

Comment: OK, clear. But why will it work for the default module like stated above?

Comment: I suspect that it might be a bug. Please, report this as issue on phalcon's github

Answer (score 0):

Try to set namespace

```
'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Api\Controllers']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first pattern is a catch-all which sends all routes to the admin controller. Have you tried putting the admin module route at the end?

Alternatively, you could use a pattern that includes the module:

```
$router->add("/:module/:controller/:action/:params", array(
    'module' => 1,
    'controller' => 2,
    'action' => 3,
    'params' => 4
));
```